# Dataframe multiplication with multiple index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Data: [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5h03ibrju3ilbig/01EconMod_EU1.xlsx?dl=0)

Question:
I have several data sheets which I export to Python as dataframes. I want to perform multiplications across these dataframes, which will generate another dataframe that takes the same dimension as the dataframes I use and/or augment the dimension (i.e. the index) based on the combination from the different dataframes used. However, I stumble upon some issues to which I could not find a solution. Below is the code.

Code:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Load the pandas library
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Load the dataframes
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

##Supply at the gridcell level (in Pj per year)
biosup = pd.read_excel('01EconMod_EU1.xlsx', sheet_name = 'biosup', skiprows = 5, index_col = 0, usecols = 'A:K')


##Cost at the gridcell level (in MEUR per Pj)
biocost = pd.read_excel('01EconMod_EU1.xlsx', sheet_name = 'biocost', skiprows = 5, index_col = 0, usecols = 'A:K')

##Demand at the gridcell level (in Pj per year)
biodem = pd.read_excel('01EconMod_EU1.xlsx', sheet_name = 'biodem', skiprows = 5, index_col = [0,1], usecols = 'A:L')

##Inter-gridcell distance matrix (in km)
dist = pd.read_excel('01EconMod_EU1.xlsx', sheet_name = 'distance', skiprows = 5, index_col = 0, usecols = 'A:AE')

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Definition of model parameter
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

##Power parameter for the distance-decay component (gamma)
gamma = pd.DataFrame({'sim1':[1.06],'sim2':[1.59],'sim3':[2.12]})
gamma = gamma.transpose()
gamma.columns = ['val']

##Inter-gridcell distance range for the supply curve determination (dmaxsup in km)
dmaxsup = pd.DataFrame({'dsup1':[390],'dsup2':[770],'dsup3':[1050]})
dmaxsup = dmaxsup.transpose()
dmaxsup.columns = ['dmax']

##Inter-gridcell distance range for the distance-decay (dmaxdem in km)
dmaxdem = pd.DataFrame({'ddem1':[750],'ddem2':[1000]})
dmaxdem = dmaxdem.transpose()
dmaxdem.columns = ['dmax']

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#New parameter calculation
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

##The ratio of the inter-gridcell distance and the dmaxdem
dist1 = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(dist.values / dmaxdem.values[:, None]), pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dmaxdem.index, dist.index]), dist.columns)

##The decay coefficients
decay = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(2 * (1 / (1 + (np.exp(dist1.values)**gamma.values[:, None])))), pd.MultiIndex.from_product([gamma.index, dist1.index]), dist1.columns)

decay1 = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(2 * (1 / (1 + (np.exp(dist.values / dmaxdem.values[:, None])**gamma.values[:, None])))), pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dmaxdem.index, gamma.index, dist.index]), dist.columns)
```

Comments on the code:

1/The parameter "dist1" represents the division of the "dist" dataframe by each of the element of the "dmaxdem" dataframe. Think of the values of the "dmaxdem" dataframe are distance scenarios. In other words, this operation computes the ratio for each of the distance values prodived.

2/ I try to compute a distance decay coefficients, i.e. "decay" dataframe, as defined by the formula inside the brackets. However, I get the following error message

```
NotImplementedError: isna is not defined for MultiIndex
```

which I believe has something to do with the multiindex structure of the "dist1" dataframe. I have tried a direct approach by embedding the previous operation, and which will require the use of the 3 different dataframes as illustrated by the code for "decay1". I get the following error

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,30,30) (3,1,1)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pardon me if I misunderstood you because I am unable to comment before posting answer:

Well, if they are all the same length, and have the same index, you can start off by first concatenation them along the 0 axis. This will create a larger dataframe. Next, you can assert a conditional column or columns that you need:

```
largerdf = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3 , dfn], axis=0)
largerdf[“calculationcolumn”] = largerdf[“columnvalue1”] *largerdf[“columnvalue2”]
```

Or change the operand to any you need.

Comment: Thank for the answer. But I am afraid that is not what I am looking for. First, the dataframes do not have the same dimension or length.  Second, the operation I am performing are not just simple concatenation.